# bxslider wrong code implementation

Tags: bxslider

I have troubles with getting BXslider to work. Problem is that only thing it does is ordinary list - not slideshow. I have no idea what is wrong with my code. I was fallowing all the steps and I was even looking at others websites code. All .js and .css files are linked properly.

Check out my code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: 'true',
    auto: 'true',
    autoControls: 'false',
  });
  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>

 <ul class="bxslider">
  <li> blablabla</li>
  <li> blablabla</li>
  <li> blablabla</li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post if there is any error displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change order of the script source  like below  and remove , after 'false'

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>



    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: 'true',
    auto: 'true',
    autoControls: 'false'
  });
  });
```